# Radio and Checkbox not validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side-validation

I want to validate all types of input of my form but only radio button and checkbox not validate.

Here is my code

```
function validateFormSection() {
    var valid = true;
    var section = $('.tab-pane.active');
    var inputs = section.find('input, select, textarea','radio','checkbox');

    var focusElem;

    inputs.each(function(index, el) {
        var elem = $(el); 
        if (elem.prop('required')) { 
            if (elem.val() == "") {
                elem.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                valid = false;
            }
        }

    });



    if (!valid) {
        focusElem.focus();
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Please never use the jQuery Validate tag unless the question is specifically about this plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

`find('input, select, textarea','radio','checkbox');`

Radio and checkbox aren't elements. You are basically saying, find all elements called `<radio>` or `<checkbox>`.

That won't be an issue as `input` will encapsulate those elements aswell. The issue comes from the arguments to `find`. You have 3 arguments when only one is needed.

`find('input, select, textarea');`

If you want to explicitly check for radios and checkboxes you could use:

`find('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]')`

Answer (score 0):

Well technically Checkbox and Radio buttons are always valid because they are binary. but if you want to see if a checkbox is checked that How I do it in jQuery:

```
$("#chkInclude").is(':checked')
```